# ng-if and col col-50 don't seem to go together?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to generate a table using angular code in HTML. Now I seem to have how I want the table to look which is how I have set up this code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-25">Date</div>
  <div class="col col-50">Name of Customer</div>
  <div class="col col-25">Hours Used</div>
</div>
```

What I have done is generated a list in angular code (which is done correctly) and I have ordered them in a certain way with Date being the first entry and Hours Used being the last. To generate the table in HTML, I use this code:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div ng-repeat="B in ConvertToTableRow(T) track by $index">
     <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index == 0">
       {{ B }} &nbsp
     </div>
     <div class="col col-50" ng-if="$index == 1">
         {{ B }} &nbsp
     </div>
     <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index == 2">
         {{ B }} &nbsp
     </div>                   
   </div>          
</div>
```

Everything in the first row works well and styled to what I need it to be but the second entry (when the index is 1) will never style its table to a col-50 but instead will stick with a col-25. Now I have tested to see the if the values are equal to 1 or 2 but it seems that is working correctly and the infomation is also coming out correctly but its just not styling correctly.

Is it possible to style a table this way using Angular and HTML?

Comment: I'm curious to know if the answer we worked out below solved your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to implement it yet, been held up with some other things. Should have an answer to you today!

Comment: So no luck sadly on my end. I even tried writing an angular function that takes the index and returns the class I want and though the HTML is setup correctly, the page always comes back wrong.

Comment: Could you share a plunker so that I could help you take a look?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of communication. Turns out my divs were set up incorrectly and they weren't spreading properly. Thanks for your help though, it did help a lot!

Comment: Awesome! If the answer below is correct, could you mark it as so? Thanks

Comment: Done, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it not be better to use `ng-class`? I think there's an even better way, but this is just off the top of my head. I hope this helps! :) Documentation for [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
 <div class="row">
   <div ng-repeat="B in ConvertToTableRow(T) track by $index">
     <div class="col" ng-class="{'col-25': $index % 3 !== 1, 'col-50': $index % 3 === 1}">
       {{ B }} &nbsp
     </div>              
   </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: Need to use modulo `%` for `$index >2` but `ng-class` definitely far more efficient approach

Comment: @charlietfl oh why is that so? Do you mean it has to be something like `$index % 2 === 0`? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm..maybe I'm misunderstanding the question @charlieftl, but could it be that I'm forgetting to account for zero indexing? `$index + 1 % 2 === 0`

Comment: To get middle column of 3 would be `$index %3 ==1`

Comment: See it better here: `var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];arr.forEach((n,i)=> console.log([n, i%3 ===1  ]))`

Comment: Let me update my answer and see if I understand you correctly. I think using modulo kind of operates as a boolean flag where the second operand is the total number of columns we have and if the remainder is equal to 1 then we know that this row needs `col-50` otherwise use `col-25`.